# Fitting Curve to Histogram in python

Tags: python, pandas, distribution, curve-fitting

I created an Histogram from my pandas dataframe and I would like to fit a probability distribution to the Histogram. I tried it myself, but the curve is not good enough
[image: Histogram & Curve].
My code so far is following:

```
h=sorted(df_distr['Strecke'])
m = df_distr['Strecke'].mean()
std = df_distr['Strecke'].std()
h=sorted(df_distr['Strecke'])
distr=(df_distr['Strecke'])

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))

# the histogram of the data
binwidth = range(-1,500)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(h, bins=binwidth, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75, histtype='step')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Strecke': bins[:-1]+1, 'Propability': n})

# add a 'best fit' line  
y = mlab.normpdf( bins, m, std)
l = plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--', linewidth=1)
```

Are there any possibilities to fit the curve much better? Are there also other distributions like Halfnorm, lognorm or Weibull to work with?

**UPDATE**
Finally i could find the best Distribution for my dataset. The following code is implemented:

```
#the histogram of the data
binwidth = range(-1,500)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(h, bins=binwidth, normed=1, facecolor='cyan', alpha=0.5, label="Histogram")
xt=plt.xticks()[0]
xmin, xmax = 0,max(xt)
lnspc = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,500)

m,s = stats.norm.fit(h)
pdf_g=stats.norm.pdf(lnspc,m,s)
#plt.plot(lnspc,pdf_g, label="Normal")

ag,bg,cg = stats.gamma.fit(h)  
pdf_gamma = stats.gamma.pdf(lnspc, ag, bg,cg)  
#plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_gamma, label="Gamma")

ab,bb,cb,db = stats.beta.fit(h)  
pdf_beta = stats.beta.pdf(lnspc, ab, bb,cb, db)  
#plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_beta, label="Beta")

gevfit = gev.fit(h)  
pdf_gev = gev.pdf(lnspc, *gevfit)  
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_gev, label="GEV")

logfit = stats.lognorm.fit(h)  
pdf_lognorm = stats.lognorm.pdf(lnspc, *logfit)  
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_lognorm, label="LogNormal")

weibfit = stats.weibull_min.fit(h)  
pdf_weib = stats.weibull_min.pdf(lnspc, *weibfit)  
#plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_weib, label="Weibull")

exponweibfit = stats.exponweib.fit(h)  
pdf_exponweib = stats.exponweib.pdf(lnspc, *exponweibfit)  
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_exponweib, label="Exponential Weibull")

paretofit = stats.pareto.fit(h)
pdf_pareto = stats.pareto.pdf(lnspc, *paretofit)
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_pareto, label ="Pareto")

plt.legend()


df = pd.DataFrame({'Strecke': bins[:-1]+1, 'Propability': n})
#R²
slope, intercept, r_value_norm, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['Propability'],pdf_g)
#print ("R-squared Normal Distribution:", r_value_norm**2)

slope, intercept, r_value_gamma, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['Propability'],pdf_gamma)
#print ("R-squared Gamma Distribution:", r_value_gamma**2)

slope, intercept, r_value_beta, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['Propability'],pdf_beta)
#print ("R-squared Beta Distribution:", r_value_beta**2)

slope, intercept, r_value_gev, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['Propability'],pdf_gev)
#print ("R-squared GEV Distribution:", r_value_gev**2)

slope, intercept, r_value_lognorm, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['Propability'],pdf_lognorm)
#print ("R-squared LogNormal Distribution:", r_value_lognorm**2)

slope, intercept, r_value_weibull, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['Propability'],pdf_weib)
#print ("R-squared Weibull Distribution:", r_value_weibull**2)

slope, intercept, r_value_exponweibull, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['Propability'],pdf_exponweib)

slope, intercept, r_value_pareto, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['Propability'],pdf_pareto)
```

As an example I get these plots:
[image: Final Plot of fitted curves]
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You are fitting this to a Gauss curve. Looking at the plot this not a normal distribution. Try to plot the logarithmic data first and see if this fits.

Comment: Looks more like exponential distribution to me

Comment: Would you please post a link to the raw data from which the histogram was created? I have an online statistical distributions fitter that fits over 80 known statistical distributions, I can run the data through it and see what it finds.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Here is the link to the raw data I get: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9ew2roz63gtev5/RawData.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: My online fitter returned scipy's "exponentiated Weibull distribution" as one of the top fits, the scipy link with distribution details is http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.exponweib.html. The fitter returned a = 6.0497751482188122E-01, c = 7.8803202648996623E-02, location = -4.3012573254302667E-45, and scale = 6.7614341194761882E-02 The scipy docs state that the probability density function for `exponweib` is: "exponweib.pdf(x, a, c) = a * c * (1-exp(-x**c))**(a-1) * exp(-x**c)*x**(c-1)"

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thanks for helping! Exponentiated Weibull is a good Distribution for this dataset. I finally was able to fit diffrent Distribution and analyze them. The Log-normal distribution is the best fit after comparing the R-sqaures and Residual sum of squares. I will update the first post to show, how I implemented them.

Comment: Question on the plot image: though the plotted distributions appear visually similar, the inset shows one of the R-squared values to be negative, and the SSE values range from 0.02 to 8.2E44, these values seem odd so it would be good to quickly double-check them.

Comment: @JamesPhillips You are right. I have to check those tomorrow.

Comment: The high numbers usually occur when zero is the input value. When calculating the SSE, I can do without this comparison at zero, and then get normal values for SSE.